# TypeScript: Cannot get values or key from Map

Tags: angular, typescript

my problem is that when I'm trying to access map keys or values by method i still get error:

> ERROR TypeError: factors.values is not a function or its return value
> is not iterable

These are model interfaces that I use for object types:

```js
export interface Plant{
    name: string;
    templateName: string;
}

export interface RiskFactor {
    riskId: number;
    name: string;
    slotName: string;
    factorType: string;
    plantType: string;
}

export interface Symptom {
    symptomId: number;
    name: string;
    slotName: string;
    plantType: string;
    checked: boolean;
}


export interface DiagnoseForm {

    riskFactors: Map<string, RiskFactor[]>;
    symptoms: Symptom[];

}
```

I save server response with DiagnoseForm to "formData" variable, and I can access and create formArray
from symptoms normally:

```js
  buildSymptoms(){
  const arr = this.formData.symptoms.map(symptom => {
    symptom.checked = false;
    return this.formBuilder.control(false);
  });
  return this.formBuilder.array(arr);
  }
```

When I try to get these riskFactors arrays from map I get error from above to the following code:

```js
  buildRiskFactors(){


    const factors: Map<string, RiskFactor[]> = this.formData.riskFactors;

    for( let wrapper of factors.values()){
      console.log(wrapper);
    }

  }
```

I've tried to solve this in many ways but each and every one give the same output.

Comment: Could you please log the `this.formData.riskFactors` before accessing it and also `this.formData.riskFactors.toString()`?

Comment: Are you sure  `this.formData.riskFactors` has type of `Map<string, RiskFactor[]>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do Object.values(factors) instead of factors.values()

Comment: Oh thanks, it solved my problem right away! Your're awesome.